# Merging config files (or XML) in C#

Tags: c#, xml, merge

What would be the fastest way, to merge 2 XML files, so I would locate a node in first one, empty it, take all children from the same tag (same node) in second XML and put it in the first one.

Comment: Please provide example inputs and desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load both files into two `XElement` objects, locate the target nodes in both objects and do the switch.

Here is a sample:

```
var nodes1 = XDocument.Parse(file1).Element("test").Element("nodes");
var nodes2 = XDocument.Parse(file2).Element("test").Element("nodes");

nodes1.Nodes().Remove();
nodes1.Add(nodes2.Nodes());
```

Here is the XML snippet i tried it on:

```
<test>
    <nodes>
        <node id="1">
            Hi
        </node>
        <node id="2">
            Hi again
        </node>
        <node id="3">
            Hi once more
        </node>
    </nodes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article on MSDN: [Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311530)

I think this is the bit of code you are looking for:

```
try
{
    XmlTextReader xmlreader1 = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Books1.xml");
    XmlTextReader xmlreader2 = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Books2.xml");

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(xmlreader1);
    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
    ds2.ReadXml(xmlreader2);
    ds.Merge(ds2);
    ds.WriteXml("C:\\Books.xml");
    Console.WriteLine("Completed merging XML documents");
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    Console.Write(ex.Message);
}
Console.Read();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That technique will only work for that very small subset of XML documents that can be parsed into DataSets,  For instance, add a second <author> element under any of the <book> elements in the input, and you'll get a DuplicateNameException.

Comment: He did ask for the quickest way.